# User-defined Keras callbacks between forward and backward propagation

Tags: python, callback, keras

I'm relatively new to Keras. If I understand correctly how training works, Keras will take batches of samples as input and, for each batch, run forward propagation, produce the output of the loss function, and then update the network by doing backpropagation.

Is there any way to have a callback called in-between forward propagation and backward propagation?

I saw the page here https://keras.io/callbacks/
but it doesn't seem to have such a mechanism.

Comment: What exact kind of computation do you want to do between forward and back-propagation? I don't think you can do this with a callback.

Comment: For now I would like to measure the relative duration of forward propagation vs. backward propagation for research purpose.